# Which Star Wars character is this figurine?

Tags: star-wars, toys

A friend was wondering if these were produced as cake toppers or custom made.
I feel confident that the [Scout Trooper is from the Power of Jedi line](http://jedibusiness.com/figureDetails.aspx?id=769)

[image]

The other various troopers and Vader are less interesting/notable but solid info would be fun...however, the truly puzzling one is the female figure:

[image]

I have no memory of the costume, hair style, nor can I find any action figure resembling her.

**Is this figure representing a real Star Wars character?**

(even if we can't find the figure in question, I would at least like to determine if it is representative of an actual character / costume)

Comment: Padme, probably

Comment: @Valorum  Hairstyle looks similar to the upbraid 'do Leia had at the Yavin awards and on Hoth.

Comment: I searched for action figures of both of those and failed - I don't recall either character having a costume like that @Valorum

Comment: @Valorum - And if [this figure](http://a.dilcdn.com/bl/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2015/03/02_ParksBlog_StarWarsDTechMe2015_Options-1088x816.jpg) is supposed to be leia, that's the squashiest faced leia I've ever seen.

Comment: http://thetoybox1138.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/star-wars-power-of-jedi.html - Not one of these

Comment: as far as I could - I searched this entire database: http://jedibusiness.com/ @Valorum (but certainly could have missed it)

Comment: I strongly suspect that it's some version of padmé from the Geonisis arena escape. She appears to be wearing handcuffs

Comment: but - black boots and a coat? that's entirely unlike the scene in question

Comment: found nothing here: http://jedibusiness.com/figuresByMovie.aspx @Valorum

Comment: Can you get a better pic of the figurine? Ideally any distinguishing marks or writing on the feet/back

Comment: I doubt it - it was shared to me from a different site of unknown origin @Valorum :(

Comment: @NKCampbell - It appears to be a mash of several figures. Padmé's bun hairstyle from AOTC, her outfit from the droid factory scene (with a weird stripe and black rather than tan shoes) and the handcuffs from the geonosis arena scene.

Comment: I’ve been looking around and I can’t find this figurine or even a picture it could be referenced from. Are we sure it’s Star Wars and not just misappropriated because it looks similar?

Comment: only assuming star wars because of the context of the other figures but yeah - I think definitely leaning w/ Valorum that it's a mash-up custom. I can't even find a costume matching this description @amflare

Comment: Based on facial structure it's supposed to be Padme I'd guess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a repainted version of [Queen Amidala (Naboo)](http://www.rebelscum.com/episodeIamidalanaboo.asp) from the Episode 1 toy line. Her maroon robes have been repainted white, and the gold stripe down the side has been repainted black. It also matches the stance of her feet and the figure's arm pose (right elbow bent 90 degrees, left elbow bent 45 degrees).

[image]

Her hairstyle looks odd because it's seen from such a high angle, so you can see the curve of her complex buns, which reach nearly past the crown of the figure's head.

[image]

Comment: well done! your id is aptly chosen :D

Comment: @NKCampbell Thanks, I try :)